# Update Incremented Quantity in Order Item Total?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to update item totals when an image card is clicked ***and*** update the corresponding totals and prices in an order panel. See screenshot.

I'm currently incrementing the quantity total onclick in the black circle `qty-icon` div on the image card using the "Update food quantity" function below which increments the number, but how do I pass that incremented value to the "0 Items" field in the `add-order-panel` panel at the bottom and update the price in "Add to Order"?

[Link to GitHub repo](https://github.com/SDillon001/safe-and-sound)
[Live GitHub page](https://gitfolio.stevedillon.net/safe-and-sound/food-menu.html)

[image]

```
// Update food quantity
    $(function() {
        $('.food-container').click( function() {
            var num = $(this).find('.qty-icon');
            num.text( parseInt(num.text()) + 1 );
        });
    });
```

---

```
<!-- Sliders -->
<div class="food-container">
    <div class="food-icon">
        <div class="qty-icon">0</div>
        <img src="images/food/icons/sliders.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="food-details">
        <div class="food-title left">
            <h4>Sliders</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="food-title right">
            <h4>$5</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
<!-- Add to Order Panel -->
<div class="add-order-panel down">
    <!-- Order Buttons -->
    <div class="order-buttons">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="order-but-container one">
                <h4><span class="bold-cash">0</span> Items</h4>
            </div>
        </a>

        <a href="#">
            <div class="order-but-container two">
                <div class="order-label">
                    <h4>Add to Order</h4>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h4><span class="bold-cash">$0</span></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm assuming you want it to add the value of everything that's clicked and not just match that one item correct? Why not just save the value of each incremented item into a variable and then add those variables inside the function that's run when you click the button. Then update the value of the total sum of all of the items stored in the variables.

FYI a framework like React or JQuery makes something like this significantly easier. Especially React.

Comment: Thanks Chris, yes, I do want to add/update the values of each item clicked. I agree with your pseudo code solution but my javascript skills are pretty basic. I don't know how to structure your solution. I am using JQuery, I haven't learned React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.each` loop to iterate through your `food-container` div then inside this you need to get `qty` ,`price` and add them to some variable . Finally ,show these values insid your `total` & item quantity spans.

***Demo code*** :

```js
$(function() {
  $('.food-container .qty-icon').click(function() {
    var num = $(this);
    num.text(parseInt(num.text()) + 1);
    var qty = 0;
    var total = 0;
    //loop through your food conatiner divs
    $(".food-container").each(function() {
      //add total qty on evry iteration
      qty += parseInt($(this).find(".qty-icon").text())
      //get actual qty
      var qty_of_item = parseInt($(this).find(".qty-icon").text())
      //mutliply it with price add total
      total += parseInt($(this).find('.price').text().replace('$', '')) * qty_of_item;
      
    })
    $(".order-but-container.one .bold-cash").text(qty); //set new qty
    $("#total").text("$" + total) //set total

  });
});
```

```css
.food-container {
  width: 105px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-bottom: 5px
}

.food-icon {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 20px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Order Buttons -->
<div class="order-buttons">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="order-but-container one">
      <h4><span class="bold-cash">0</span> Items</h4>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="order-but-container two">
      <div class="order-label">
        <h4>Add to Order</h4>
      </div>

      <div>
        <!--added here id-->
        <h4><span id="total" class="bold-cash">$0</span></h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="food-container">
  <div class="food-icon">
    <div class="qty-icon">0</div>
    <img src="images/food/icons/sliders.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="food-details">
    <div class="food-title left">
      <h4>pizza</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="food-title right">
      <!--added here class-->
      <h4 class="price">$10</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="food-container">
  <div class="food-icon">
    <div class="qty-icon">0</div>
    <img src="images/food/icons/sliders.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="food-details">
    <div class="food-title left">
      <h4>burger</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="food-title right">
      <h4 class="price">$5</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="food-container">
  <div class="food-icon">
    <div class="qty-icon">0</div>
    <img src="images/food/icons/sliders.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="food-details">
    <div class="food-title left">
      <h4>somethings</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="food-title right">
      <h4 class="price">$5</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="add-order-panel down">
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much! I was trying to use innerHTML to replace the div text bc I forgot about `.text()` which is much easier. Thanks again, I really appreciate the time you put into your response. I'm a visual person and its easier for me to understand how code is working by looking at examples. Happy new year!

Answer (score 0):

You're over thinking it :) You're already storing the element your wanting into a variable called "num". Then you're grabbing the text inside of it. Here's what you do.

1. redefine num to be the text of the element.
2. do this for every other element you want to update the text for.
3. then add all of the values of those inside the function.
4. save that in a var called total and update that in the area where the total should be
5. make sure to start total at 0 every time the function runs or you will compound the value

note you'll want to declare all of your variables globally and then update them locally. Don't declare any variables locally or they will come back undefined when you try to update them in other functions

```
$(function() {
let total = 0
$('.food-container').click( function() 
{var num = $(this).find('.qty-icon'); 
num = num.text( parseInt(num.text()) + 1 ); 
total = num + otherVar  + yetAnotherVar});});
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm just not seeing it. I haven't worked with js/jq in a few years. The user's currently clicking multiple images in the `.food-container` div to update the quantity but how does that value get updated in other divs? And how is the same value displayed in the 'Items 0' field? Then how does that value get updated based on the price of each item to produce the total order dollar amount in the 'Add to Order $0' field? Example: I click on the 'Sliders' image so I have 1 item at $5. Then I click on the 'Hot Dogs' image so I have 2 items at $5. The item total is 2 and the order total is $10